# How to structure Flask + Reactjs projects

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

My question is how to structure the directories when you are creating an app that uses both Flask(backend) and Reactjs (frontend).
The default structures for each individual infrastructures are below:

In Flask, the structure is:

```
.
├── app.py
├── static
│   ├── foo.png
│   └── bar.csv
├── templates
│   ├── Predict.html
│   ├── home.html
│   ├── index.html
│   └── something.js
└── utlities.py
```

In React apps, the structure (when running create-react-app) is:

```
.
├── node_modules
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── logo192.png
│   ├── logo512.png
│   ├── manifest.json
│   └── robots.txt
└── src
    ├── App.css
    ├── App.js
    ├── App.test.js
    ├── index.css
    ├── index.js
    ├── logo.svg
    ├── serviceWorker.js
    └── setupTests.js
```

Answer (score 3):

the way it has become standard is to keep the front end and backend separate, if using react they should not have html files in the flask project folders (it would only work for data handling)

Comment: When you run the flask app doesn't it automatically look for the html files in the templates directory? How do you get it to look for the js files in the src directory instead? Thanks

Comment: its better your backend server dont serve the frontend files, you can use the serve package to run  the frontend using `npm run build` and `serve -s build`

Answer (score -1):

Assuming we want to build a hello template I would first use the standard Flask folder organization :

```
.
├── hello_template
    ├── configurations.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── README.md
    ├── run.py
    └── templates
        ├── hello
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   └── views.py
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── public
        │   ├── css
        │   ├── fonts
        │   ├── images
        │   └── js
        └── static
            ├── index.html
            ├── __init__.py
            ├── js
               ├── components
               ├── index.jsx
               └── routes.js
```

And then add React, by opening terminal in `hello_template/templates/static/` and run the command :

```
$ npm i react react-dom --save-dev
```